# ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching

I'm developing my app on Windows with GAE, but the below error message was shown.

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can

change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment

variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

So I checked some post in this site and I found [some articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192323/what-is-the-python-egg-cache-python-egg-cache?rq=1) but I could not understand it. My understanding is that I need to create cache directory with write access in home directory, but I did not understand where "home directory" is.

Also in other post, I found the answer saying *This approach solved my issue. I did uninstall pyyaml using pip and then installed it with easy_install -z pyyaml*

Which approach is correct?

```
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
import cloudstorage
import mimetypes

from PIL import Image
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.api import images
from models import Note
from models import CheckListItem
from models import NoteFile

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

images_formats = {
'0':'image/png',
'1':'image/jpeg',
'2':'image/webp',
'-1':'image/bmp',
'-2':'image/gif',
'-3':'image/ico',
'-4':'image/tiff',
}

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is not None:
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template_context = {
            'user': user.nickname(),
            'logout_url' : logout_url,
        }
        template = jinja_env.get_template('main.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_context))
    else:
        login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        self.redirect(login_url)

def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
        self.error(401)

    bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
    uploaded_file = self.request.POST.get('uploaded_file')
    file_name = getattr(uploaded_file,'filename',None)
    file_content = getattr(uploaded_file,'file',None)
    real_path = ''
    if file_name and file_content:
        content_t = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
        real_path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + user.user_id() + "/" + file_name
        with cloudstorage.open(real_path,'w',content_type=content_t,options={'x-goog-acl':'public-read'}) as f:
            f.write(file_content.read())

    self._create_note(user, file_name, real_path)

    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    template_context = {
        'user':user.nickname(),
        'logout_url': logout_url,
    }
    self.response.out.write(self._render_template('main.html',template_context))

def _render_template(self,template_name,context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    user = users.get_current_user()
    ancestor_key = ndb.Key("User",user.nickname())
    qry = Note.owner_query(ancestor_key)
    context['notes'] = qry.fetch()
    template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    return template.render(context)


@ndb.transactional
def _create_note(self,user,file_name,file_path):
    note = Note(parent=ndb.Key("User", user.nickname()), title=self.request.get('title'), content=self.request.get('content'))
    note.put()
    item_titles = self.request.get('checklist_items').split(',')
    for item_title in item_titles:
        item = CheckListItem(parent=note.key, title=item_title)
        item.put()
        note.checklist_items.append(item.key)
    if file_name and file_path:
        url, thumbnail_url = self._get_urls_for(file_name)

        f = NoteFile(parent=note.key, name=file_name, url=url,thumbnail_url=thumbnail_url,full_path=file_path)
        f.put()

        note.files.append(f.key)
        note.put()

def _get_urls_for(self,file_name):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
        return
    bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
    path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + user.user_id() + '/' + file_name
    real_path = '/gs' + path
    key = blobstore.create_gs_key(real_path)
    try:
        url = images.get_serving_url(key, size=0)
        thumbnail_url = images.get_serving_url(key,size=150,crop=True)
    except images.TransformationError,images.NotImageError:
        url = "http://storage.googleapis.com{}".format(path)
        thumbnail_url = None

    return url,thumbnail_url



class MediaHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self,file_name):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
    content_t = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
    real_path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + user.user_id() + '/' + file_name
    try:
        with cloudstorage.open(real_path,'r')as f:
            self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type',content_t)
            self.response.out.write(f.read())
    except cloudstorage.errors.NotFoundError:
        self.abort(404)

class ShrinkHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def _shrink_note(self,note):
    for file_key in note.files:
        file = file_key.get() # this is the same as "file.get().url" in html file. we add the comment.
        try:
            with cloudstorage.open(file.full_path) as f:
                image = images.Image(f.read())
                image.resize(640)
                new_image_data = image.execute_transforms()

            content_t = images_format.get(str(image.format))
            with cloudstorage.open(file.full_path,'w',content_type=content_t) as f:
                f.write(new_image_data)
        except images.NotImageError:
            pass

def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
        login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.url)
        return self.redirect(login_url)

    ancestor_key = ndb.Key("User",user.nickname())
    notes = Note.owner_query(ancestor_key).fetch()

    for note in notes:
        self._shrink_note(note)

    self.response.write('Done.')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
(r'/', MainHandler),
(r'/media/(?P<file_name>[\w.]{0,256})',MediaHandler),
(r'/shrink',ShrinkHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're developing a standard env GAE app but you're attempting to install third party libraries in (and use them from) your local system's site packages. This won't work.

You need to install the third party libraries in your app's library directory (i.e. using `-t <your_lib_dir>` option for `pip install`, for which you shouldn't need special permissions. See also:

- [Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).
- [No module named warnings when starting GAE inside virtualenv locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983767/no-module-named-warnings-when-starting-gae-inside-virtualenv-locally/45985426#45985426)